# Problem in Ubuntu 16.04 DNS resolution

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns

My primary DNS Server is `4.2.2.4`. Sometimes my machine cannot resolve any host name like this:

```
~ ping google.com            
ping: unknown host google.com
```

But I can ping `4.2.2.4` and even lookup host names like this:

```
~ nslookup google.com 4.2.2.4
Server:     4.2.2.4
Address:    4.2.2.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.209.174
```

Restarting `network-manager` service solves this problem. I wonder what causes this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out `dns=dnsmasq` from `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and dns now works as it should.